# Winform form closed event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have 2 forms, Main and Child. When a button is clicked on the Main form, the Child form is loaded. Can I catch from the Main form, when the Child form is closed by subscribing to the closed event of the child form?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes you can, it's pretty straightforward:

```
private void LoadChildForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChildForm form = new ChildForm();
    form.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(ChildFormClosed);
    form.Show();
}

void ChildFormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    // do something useful
}
```

Comment: Tell me please, ChildFormClosed method must be a static?

Comment: @KryDos no, it does not have to be static (and it probably shouldn't be).