# Close the parent window from child window

Tags: c#, winforms

I put button on parent window to go to child window . for closing the child window i use this.close() on button click , but i want to close both parent and child window by click button of child window .

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
If Child.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
          Parent.close
        End If
```

Child form close button

```
Me.diaglogresult=DialogResult.OK
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass in the parent form into the child form and call its close method in the closed event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the close of the parent form from the child but to me that seems to break the encapsulation principle a little.

An alternative is to subscribe to the child form's closed event from the parent and then within the parent you can respond to that - see [Winform form closed event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179661/winform-form-closed-event) for an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void btnOpenForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(frm2_FormClosed);
        frm2.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }


    private void frm2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```