# .Net UserControl implementing Show and ShowDialog methods

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, parent-child, formclosing

I have a `BaseControl` class doing pretty much all I need for controls.

It is convenient for me to implement a `void Show` and `DialogResult ShowDialog` method from my control.

**UPDATE** this is for convenience as I use my `BaseControls` all over the place and, in some cases, I want the possibilit to show (show-dialog) them with easiest possible code...

Here is the code of the `ShowDialog` method, the `Show` method being very similar:

```
Form ContainingForm = null;
public DialogResult ShowDialog(string title, Control parent) {
  ContainingForm = new Form();
  this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
  ContainingForm.Controls.Add(this);
  ContainingForm.Text = title;
  // 
  DialogResult res = ContainingForm.ShowDialog();
  ContainingForm.Close();
  return res;
}

private void Close(DialogResult result) {
  if (ContainingForm != null) {
    ContainingForm.DialogResult = result;
    // original code: form is not closing...
    // ContainingForm.Close();
  }
}
// button on BaseControl closing the control
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  this.Close(DialogResult.OK);
}
```

I tried the approach suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648221/close-the-parent-window-from-child-window), hence the Close in the `ShowDialog` method. In both the original version and the revised one using the above post, the window is not closing.

I read about sending a "Close" message to the `ContainingForm` but using an `Invoke` didn't work either.

Also, shall I expect some other issues when using `Show` instead of `ShowDialog`, as the form isn't blocking the UI thread?

Anyone knowing the answer to this??

Comment: What's the problem with a `Form` which made you to try something like this?

Comment: The Form class does not have a parameterized constructor, so it's on clear what's going on here: `ContainingForm = new Form(parent);`

Comment: Inheritance for compatibility with non-winforms projects...

Comment: @LarsTech => I corrected the code, it was a typo...

Comment: If you need to `ShowDialog` a user control, you can use a `Form` instead. Also when you want to use it as a `UserControl` set `FormBorderStyle` to `None` and set its `TopLevel` to false and use it exactly like a user control.

Comment: @RezaAghaei : that's exaclty what I do but I removed code to shorten it...

Comment: You are using a `UserControl` not a `Form`.

Comment: If the only reason is the need for a parameter constructor then add one :)  Use the normal form control and just next to its default constructor, add a new one with your parameters. The form code behind is just another class and adding a parameter constructor should not be different.

Comment: I edited the question to highlight this is NOT a `Form` and I don't want to make it a 'Form` but a convenient wrapper to show the `UserControl`...

Comment: What is the question exactly?  I've try this code and it's working fine on my side.

Comment: @Kinetic indeed it works when I clean out some more code on my side. The `ContainingForm.Dispose()` did actually resolve my problems.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the following code seems to work:

```
private void Close(DialogResult result) {
  if (ContainingForm != null) {
    ContainingForm.DialogResult = result;
    ContainingForm.Close();
    ContainingForm.Dispose();
  }
}
```