# Executing code when my form is closed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My program makes some changes in the registry while it's running, and if they are not properly rolled back, they might cause the user some problems. FOr example, they might not be able to use their Internet connection.

So I need to make sure that when they close the application, I return everything back to normal. To do this, I need to know when they have pressed the Close button of the form. How can I do that? Is there an event that I can handle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what you need is not access to the close button, but rather access to the *event* which is fired when the form is closed.

Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179661/winform-form-closed-event) previous SO post, what you might need is something like so:

```
void FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    // do something useful
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is an event you can subscribe to called `FormClosing` this fire before `FormClose` and allows you to validate/change the settings you need before the form closes

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;
}

void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   // Reset values
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are more possibilites here.

1) Use the `FormClosing` event of the form:

```
private void form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing) {   // User clicked 'X' button
         if (someThing)  e.Cancel = true;             // Disable Form closing
    }
}
```

2) You can also hide the 'X' button by set `ControlBox`to false. But this will also hide the minimize and maximize buttons.

3) This disables only the 'X' button. Place it in your form.

```
    private const int CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON = 0x200;

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
        get {
            new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode).Demand();
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ClassStyle |= CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON;
            return cp;
        }
    }
```