# I have this problem with a singleton form name FCD Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'FCD'.'

Tags: c#, winforms

code error here this is an other form who content
a button to lunch the FCD form

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        f = FCD.getInstance();
        f.Show();
   

    }
```

and the class FDC is

```
public partial class FCD : Form
{
    private static FCD instance=null;
    private FCD()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        load();
    }

    public static FCD getInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new FCD();
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

the problem is when i execute the form fcd  it work for the first time when i close it i try again and they give me this problem

Comment: I think you have to override the close event and Hide the form instead of actually closing it. It's the Close action that is disposing of the form

Comment: Two things 1)  The static method in a form doesn't make a lot of sense because the form will dispose when you exit unless you capture the close event 2) Calling a new FCD inside the static method again doesn't make a lot of sense.  See my two form solution : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/mixed-native-and-managed-assemblies?view=msvc-160

Comment: When the static instance of `FCD` closes it will need to set `instance` to `null`.

Comment: yes but how can set instance to null

Comment: `instance = null;` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608188/executing-code-when-my-form-is-closed

Comment: Setting `instance` to `null` when the form closes undoes the singleton pattern. Why is a singleton needed here, anyhow?

Comment: the problem is how test if the is closed or not , i need singleton because it's must be one form and not two

Comment: Did you try setting `instance` to `null` in the event discussed in the link I gave you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if instance `IsDisposed`. Try the following:

**Change from**:

```
public static FCD getInstance()
{
    if(instance == null)
    {
        instance = new FCD();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

**To**:

```
public static FCD getInstance()
{
    if(instance == null || instance.IsDisposed)
    {
        instance = new FCD();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so after a big discussion i found this solution

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(f!=null)
        if (f.IsDisposed)
        {
            FCD.setInstanceNull();
        }

        f = FCD.getInstance();
        f.Show();
       
   

    }
```

and i add a methode who set instance = null if form closed

```
    public static void setInstanceNull()
    {
        instance = null;

    }
```

Comment: It is very weird to have the caller of the singleton worry about this kind of stuff (which is why I suggested the way I did).