# Enable/Disable Buttons On Owner Form When Owned Form Is Closed

Tags: c#, winforms, disabled-control

I am working on a WinForms Desktop application in C# .NET. The target framework is .NET Framework 4.8. When the application is started, the main form is displayed with several buttons. Each button hides the main form when clicked and opens another form that displays data with which the user interacts. The main form is the owner of the new form.

One button opens a form that presents a list of files from a network share folder in a data grid view. The user selects a row in the data grid and clicks a button to import the information in the file to various tables in a SQL Server database. When the import is complete, the selected row is removed from the data grid. When the user closes this form, there is code in the Form Closed event to show the owner. This all works well.My problem is that when the main form is unhidden, I need to disable the button that opens the form to list files to import if there are not any files in the network share folder to be imported. There is also a line of code to change the button's text property informing the user there are not any files to import.I realize I can place the code to disable the button and change button text in the VisibleChanged event. But, I only want the code to run after the owned form's closed event shows the owner form. How do I enclose the code in the main form's VisibleChanged event to disable the file import button only after the owned form is closed. Or, is it possible to edit the properties of the button on the owner form in the Form Closed event prior to the `Owner.Show();`I found a similar question [WinForm Form Closed Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179661/winform-form-closed-event?rq=1). But when I follow the suggestion

```
private void LoadChildForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChildForm form = new ChildForm();
    form.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(ChildFormClosed);
    form.Show();
}
```

substituting my names

```
private void btnImportHFR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form form = new frmHFRFiles();
   form.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(frmHFRFiles_FormClosed);
   form.Show(this);
   Hide();
}
```

Visual Studio flags `frmHFRFiles_FormClosed` as an error for the name does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Can you not disable the button when you hide the form in the first place?

Comment: The button should only be disabled when there are no files remaining in the network share folder. This would only occur if all the files listed in the data grid on the owned form were imported. Then when the user closes the owned form, the button on the owner would be disabled when the visible property is changed.

Comment: Are you passing the main form instance (this) to the owned form? If so, you could make the button public. Then in the form closing event, you could check conditions to see if you should disable the button. If so, do something like MainForm.button1.Enabled = false;

Comment: @David.Warwick The click event for the button on the main form (the owner) is shown above. The subsequent form is shown with the main form set as the owner.

Comment: @Darrell, I thought you wanted to disable the button from the ChildForm? What I gave you has nothing to do with the click event.

Comment: @DarrellEmbrey - So you're saying when the main form is made visible it should set the button to enabled or disabled based on a folder being non-empty or empty, respectively.  Is that right?

Comment: @Enigmativity That is correct. When the application is started, the menu form is loaded. The form's constructor calls a method that checks the network folder for files to be imported. If no files are in the folder, the button that opens form to import files is disabled. I do have a problem here.</p>If the network folder has files, the button is enabled. If only one file is available, and the user imports the file, when the form is closed, and the main form is displayed, the button should should be disabled.

Comment: @David.Warwick It does not matter whether the button on the main form is disabled in the closed event of the child form or the visible changed event of the main form. I only want the code that disables the button to be evaluated When the child form is closed. Since I am hiding the main form in  the button click event, the visible changed event is fired. There is no need to search the network folder again. I know there are file in the folder at this point. Otherwise, the button would have been disabled when the main form opened.

Comment: @DarrellEmbrey - So why not check the folder contents when the form becomes visible?

Comment: Ok, I guess I am confused. You say you "only want the code that disables the button to be evaluated When the child form is closed." That's what the answer I posted does.

Comment: @Enigmativity  The folder is checked when the application is started and the main form is loaded. That was not my problem. The problem was the form's visible changed event fires after the load event. There is no need to search the folder again at this point. Then the visible changed event fired because the form is hidden in the button click event. No need to check the folder for files here. If no files were in the folder, the button would have been disabled. But when we return to the main form, the folder needs to be searched again. If 0 files, the button should be disabled.

Comment: @DarrellEmbrey - Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying you should do. What's the problem with doing that?

Answer (score 2):

```
ChildForm form = new ChildForm(this);
```

Then in ChildForm constructor:

```
MainForm m_MainForm;

Public ChildForm (MainForm mainForm)
{
      m_MainForm = mainForm;
}
```

Then in closing event:

```
m_MainForm.button1.Enabled = false;
```

Ensure button1 is public

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did. I created a boolean variable in the main form and set the initial value to false.

```
private bool updateButtons = false;
```

The main form's constructor executes the search for files in the network folder.

```
public frmMainMenu()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Shared.FilesForImport = GetHFRFiles();
}
```

The form's load event calls the `EnableButtons()` method

```
public void EnableButtons()
{
    btnImportHFR.Enabled = Convert.ToBoolean(Shared.FilesForImport.Count);
    btnImportHFR.Text = btnImportHFR.Enabled ? "Find Available HFR" : "No HFR For Import";

    btnGetFacilityStatus.Enabled = Shared.sqlWrap.GetDataForFacStat(Shared.DsFacStat);
    updateButtons = false;
}
```

The main form's visible changed event fires after the form load event. The network folder is not searched again because the updateButtons value is set to false.

```
private void frmMainMenu_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(updateButtons)
    {
        EnableButtons();
    }
}
```

In the button click event, the updateButtons value is set to true after the main form is hidden.

```
private void btnImportHFR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmHFRFiles form = new frmHFRFiles();
    form.Show(this);
    Hide();

    updateButtons = true;
}
```

The child form's closed event calls the `Owner.Show()` method

```
private void frmHFRFiles_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Owner.Show();
}
```

This causes the main form's visible changed event to fire. Only this time the `EnableButtons()` method will run because the updateButtons value is true.

```
private void frmMainMenu_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(updateButtons)
    {
        EnableButtons();
    }
}

public void EnableButtons()
{
    btnImportHFR.Enabled = Convert.ToBoolean(Shared.FilesForImport.Count);
    btnImportHFR.Text = btnImportHFR.Enabled ? "Find Available HFR" : "No HFR For Import";

    btnGetFacilityStatus.Enabled = Shared.sqlWrap.GetDataForFacStat(Shared.DsFacStat);
    updateButtons = false;
}
```

Finally, the `EnableButtons()` method sets the updateButtons value to false.

It seems rudimentary to me, but it works. Thank you everyone for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that when the main form is unhidden, I need to disable the button that opens the form to list files to import if there are not any files in the network share folder to be imported. There is also a line of code to change the button's text property informing the user there are not any files to import.

So your main form has a button X. If this button is clicked a method is called. This method will first hide the form, then show the subform until the subform is closed. The method should disable button X, change the button's text and unhide the form.

To make this flexible, we won't do everything in one procedure, we make several procedures with the intention of the procedure: "Inform operator there are no files to import" "Disable opening the subform", and of course their counterparts "Enable opening the subform", "Inform operator there are files to import"

**TODO: invent proper method names**

```
private void ShowNoFilesToImport()
{
    this.buttonX.Text = ...;
}

private void DisableOpeningSubForm()
{
    this.buttonX.Text.Enabled = false;
}
```

The advantage of this, is that if you later want to change the way that you want to inform the operator, for instance if you want to use an information field at the bottom of you screen, you will only have to change this in one place.

Furthermore, you can reuse the procedures, for instance you can add a menu item that will do the same as button X, this menu item can call the same methods

```
private void PerformActionsButtonX()     // TODO: invent proper name
{
    // Hide this form, and show the Subform until it is closed
    this.Visible = false;

    using (var dlg = new SubForm())
    {
        // if needed, set properties of the subForm:
        dlg.Text = ...
        dlg.Position = ...

        // show the form until it is closed
        var dlgResult = dlg.ShowDialog();
        this.ProcessDlgResult(dlgResult, dlg);
    }

    // Show that there are no files to Import and disable OpeningSubform
    this.ShowNoFilesToImport();
    this.DisableOpeningSubform();

    // Finally: show this form:
    this.Visible = true;
}
```

And of course call this method when ButtonX or menu item Y are clicked:

```
private void OnButtonX_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    this.PerformActionsButtonX();
}
private void OnMenyItemYClicked(object sender, ...)
{
    this.PerformActionsButtonX();
}
```